# No wireless on windows after using kali boot cd

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet, kali-linux

Today I wanted to start playing around with Kali Linux so I downloaded the ISO and burned it to a DVD, restarted the laptop and booted to the DVD pressed the first option which is just a boot. Wireless was working fine and after trying some stuff out I decided to restart and go into windows 7 again only to see that I did not have a wireless connection.

After seeing that my wireless service was off I opened up services at start and went to `wlan autoconfig` it was on automatic start but not running. Trying to start it gave me an error that I cannot repeat right now because I went back to restart the laptop too kali where I had internet again

Trying to run `sfc.exe` to look for corrupted files gives me a screen that disappears in 0.3sec

**UPDATE:** This morning when I woke up I removed the battery and power lead from my laptop left it out for a minute and put everything back and put on the computer. still nothing. Also when I run `sfc`/`scannow` in cmd I get Windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation after 17% verification. After running `chkdsk` as scheduled task still nothing. Note that I did not install kali on my system only run the live cd. Suprisingly I can go into my Windows file system when I boot kali without using any Windows credentials.
I don’t know if it matters but I can connect to the Internet with wire.

Comment: My first impression is that windows expects the WiFi in an uninitialized state. One which is not met when when you warm rebooted from Kali to Windows. Can you try again after shutting down the laptop (power off, not reboot!) and then booting windows?

Comment: When powered off: if it's a laptop remove the battery and the power connector; if a desktop remove the power lead (some desktop power supplies maintain certain power rails even when the switch is off, and this can be enough to stop some interfaces doing a hard reset). I've had to do that in the past on dual-boot systems. It seems that other operating systems can leave some hardware in a state that Windows drivers can't handle, and it can be fully reset only by removing _all_ power.

Comment: Plz help further since I still dont have wifi

Comment: What commands did you enter in kali? I've had problems like this before but a restart usually fixed it. Try booting into kali again to undo the commands (if you did do something in kali).

Comment: I was trying out aircrack which uses my wifi, do you think it could be fixed if I delete aircrack from the boot cd?

Comment: What is exact model of you WiFi card?

Answer (score 0):

"Usually the wireless adapter is unable to transmit in monitor mode."

If you enabled monitor mode somewhere down the line, then it could cause this problem.

e.g. airmon-ng stop wlan0mon

Where wlan0mon is your adapter.

---

Alternativly try running elevated cmd (admin) and running sfc /scannow.

If these do not work then try getting new wireless drivers on a different computer, or using kali linux, then chuck em on a usb and run them.

[Try looking here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725782.aspx)